# An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested class: authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, xampp, localhost

I was working on my application on my localhost and after trying to switch my IDE (Expression 4 to Eclipse) with no luck, i went to my index page and got this error

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: authentication

this issue just pop up and I have no clue how to fix it. I tried changing the user permissions on the file so that all user have access but it still precise.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: post the code where you are trying to 'load' authentication class?

Comment: I'm not load authentication as I said this issue was not their until I changed my IDE  all other pages except my home page is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

in my function construct on my home page I was loading authentication but the folder that had authentication was deleted, so my page crashing because of that.

**before**

function __construct()
    {

```
    parent::__construct();

    // Load the necessary stuff...
    $this->load->helper(array('language', 'url', 'form', 'account/ssl'));
    $this->load->library(array('account/authentication'));
    $this->load->model(array('account/account_model'));
    $this->lang->load(array('general'));
}
```

**after**

function __construct()
    {

parent::__construct();

```
    // Load the necessary stuff...
    $this->load->helper(array('language', 'url', 'form'));

    $this->lang->load(array('general'));
}
```

I hope this helps someone